# Jinja2 templates and Excel file

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to use a jinja2 template to write some configurations file. I have already created the template with curly braces. I am using an excel file to store all the values. the problem i am looking at is that it is not scalable as I need to enter the data.value for each cell against every variable, I have more than 40 variables. Is there a way to read the values without manually telling typing each cell and also to deal with the render command the same way

I am very new to Python and only tried what I have pasted below.

```
import openpyxl
import jinja2
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from jinja2 import Template
output = []

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('C:\\Python\\Templates'))
template1 = env.get_template('config.cfg')

xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook("templates.xlsx")
xsheets = xfile.sheetnames
data = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('variables')

DST_ROUTE1 = data['e24'].value
DST_ROUTE2 = data['e25'].value
DST_ROUTE3 = data['e26'].value
DST_ROUTE4 = data['e27'].value
DST_PREFIX1 = data['e28'].value
DST_PREFIX2 = data['e29'].value
DST_PREFIX3 = data['e30'].value
DST_PREFIX4 = data['e31'].value

output.append(template1.render(DST_ROUTE1=DST_ROUTE1, DST_ROUTE2=DST_ROUTE2, DST_PREFIX1=DST_PREFIX1))

with open("C:\\Python\\script.txt", mode='w+') as f:
f.writelines(output)
```

Comment: You can simply pass `data` to your template and use `{{ data.e29.value }}` within the template itself. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You would assign the whole dictionary to the template and loop through it there.

```
import openpyxl
import jinja2
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from jinja2 import Template
output = []

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('C:\\Python\\Templates'))
template1 = env.get_template('config.cfg')

xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook("templates.xlsx")
xsheets = xfile.sheetnames
data = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('variables')

output.append(template1.render(sheets_by_name=data))

with open("C:\\Python\\script.txt", mode='w+') as f:
    f.writelines(output)
```

the template would look something like this:

```
<table>
{% for key, sheet in sheets_by_name.items() %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ key }}</td><td>{{ sheet.value }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

assuming python3 here, otherwise it's .iteritems() I believe

You can also use a subtemplate and keep the logic inside python

```
template1 = env.get_template('table_frame.tmpl')
subtemplate1 = env.get_template('table_row.tmpl')
sheets = ""

for key, sheet in data.items():
    sheets += subtemplate1.render(key=key, sheet=sheet)

output.append(template1.render(sheets=sheets))
```

table_frame.tmpl

```
<table>
    {{ sheets }}
</table>
```

table_row.tmpl

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ key }}</td><td>{{ sheet }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I am sorry but i am not able to follow much .I did pick one from this is that to convert the excel data into a dictionary, which i tried with the df.to_dict() function of pandas which gave the value and key values nicely. Guess i need to figure out how to read those values and put them in the template which is basically a config file for a Cisco device

Comment: I don't understand this comment. How does that relate to the answer? What part don't you understand? I've even used your own code and adapted it.

Comment: Mate, I said I was new to Python and hence trouble understanding what you asked me to do. Can you please mention it again for python3. I am a network engg and looking at scripting certain implementation plans that I might do over and over again. you mentioned some templates, where do I put them ?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know how to explain it any better. Especially not without you telling me where exactly you are getting stuck.